# Why does Perl DBI require a prepare statement before execution?

Tags: php, mysql, perl

I am currently working on a bit of Perl script and I am very new to it. I ran into a problem with Perl because I am accustomed to Php's syntax of MySQL where you create the statement you want and then execute it and then it sends the information to the server-side.

However, with Perl and the DBI module, it requires that you create the statement, prepare the statement, and then execute the statement sending the information to the server-side.

Is it because Perl is similar to a high-level programming language and has a practical compiler inside of it that it requires this prepare statement before execution?

I am using a MySQL update statement, is it specific on the statements (update vs select)?

When I say 'create the statement' I mean something like:

```
$query = "UPDATE table SET column = value";
```

Maybe I haven't done enough research on the topic?

Comment: You too should be using the create, prepare, execute methodology of mysqli or PDO in your PHP code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You actually don't have to use `prepare` directly (there are some shortcuts.) But using it allows you to tell the database driver about a single statement which can be repeatedly executed without the database having to recompile it every time. For example

```
my @records = ( [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ], [ 7, 8 9 ] );
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( "INSERT INTO foo VALUES ( ?, ?, ? )" );
foreach my $record( @records ) { 
    $sth->execute( @$record );
}
```

This will execute the same prepared statement three times, one for each set of three values in `@records`. This also demonstrates the use of `?` placeholders, which you should always use instead of interpolating variables directly into SQL strings.

If you only need to execute a statement once, you can combine the prepare and execute statements into a single step:

```
$dbh->do( "INSERT INTO foo VALUES ( ?, ?, ? )", undef, 1, 2, 3 );
```

The first argument is the SQL string (preferable with placeholders) the seconds is an optional attributes hash (left `undef` here) and the remaining params are what gets substituted in for the placeholders.

Comment: This also makes a lot of sense too! I appreciate this!

Comment: Simple, straight forward and easy to understand explanation. +1.

Comment: Also worth mentioning the various handy `select*_*()` methods that provide a simple way to prepare, execute and fetch data in a single call. For example `$dbh->selectall_arrayref("SELECT ... WHERE foo = ?", undef, $foo)`.

Answer (score 10):

You only need to prepare() if you want to execute the query more than once without parsing it every time.

For your simple, case, I'd use the [do](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm#do) method.

```
$query = "UPDATE table SET column = value";
$rows = $dbh->do($query) or die $dbh->errstr;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes ten times more sense!

Comment: Though even with the `do` method, making use of bind values is *much* safer than interpolating data into your query string.

Comment: @tjd, yeah, I support the use of query parameters, and the `do` method makes that easy.